# How to use a filter in queryset, so users are limited to view their own answers?

Tags: filter, django-views, django-queryset

I made an application form. A user can use this form many times. Everytime a user uses the form, the input is added to the queryset in views.py. Now, I want users to see only their input in the html file. The filter i'm using in my views does not seem to work. Could anybody help me?

```
def requestlist(request):
object_list = MODEL.objects.all().order_by('timestamp')
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    object_list = MODEL.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
else:
    raise PermissionDenied

context = {
    "object_list": queryset,
}   
return render(request, "requestlist.html", context)
```

All ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the object_list in the context as there is no 'queryset' variable

```
def requestlist(request):
object_list = MODEL.objects.all().order_by('timestamp')
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    object_list = MODEL.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
else:
    raise PermissionDenied
context = {
    "object_list": object_list,
}   
return render(request, "requestlist.html", context)
```